# Need to pull data from 2 tables, trying to use an include but it is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple problem. I have 2 tables: Followers (with columns id, user1, user2) and Users (with columns id, name, address).

I want to get all the user data for the followers of a given user. I.e. in as efficient a query as possible, I want to do this: Followers.find_all_by_id(10). Then, for each of the followers in that list, I want to look them up in the Users table.

I can obviously do a big for loop, but I also know I can use an includes statement here. I'm just not able to figure out how to do it. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Follow.includes(:user).where('user1=?',current_user.id)
```

That doesn't work (the result I get is just a subsection of the Follow table).

Thanks for your help!
Ringo

Here's what my models look like...

Follow.rb:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo_taker, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

User.rb:

```
has_many :followings, :class_name => 'Follow', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followers, :class_name => 'Follow', :foreign_key => 'user2', :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: Provide your models code: Follow and User

Comment: Hi Valery - I've added that to my post.

Comment: is user1 - id of :photo_taker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Follow:
belongs_to :photo_taker, :foreign_key => :user2, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user1

# User:
has_many :followings, :class_name => 'Follow', :foreign_key => :user1, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followers, :through => :followings, :source => :photo_taker, :dependent => :destroy

user.followers
#=> returns following users
```

If you need exactly Follow objects with included followers.

```
user.followings.includes(:photo_taker)
```